# $.ajax() methods data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some div tags which onchange I want to insert the new value into my database.
As people suggest, I'm using `$.ajax POST` to insert. Since I'm new to JQuery and Ajax, I don't what actually that data and msg in $.ajax()..Please explain how to insert my value into a database asynchronously (on the Fly)

```
            $(".div"+increment).change(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "./server",
                     data: "name=John&location=Boston",
                     success: function(msg){
                     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
                          }
                })


               });
```

Comment: I see you've found the tutorial (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).  It's hard for us to help you more without knowing what your server-side code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "insert my value to database asynchronously....(on the Fly)", I hope you mean "insert into the database, period".

The POST request (either by $.ajax() or by $.post() ) can only send your data from the client to you server.

You will need to write server side code to do the insertion.

Lets say you have a script called "do-insertion.php" on your server that can insert data into a database, if the POST variables "name" and "location" are submitted to it.

So you would write (I guess you already know this):

`$.post( "do-insertion.php",
{"name":"John", "location":"SF"},
function(data){alert("got response="+data);} );`

The important thing is what you write on the server side code. I assume PHP, so you would use the mysql API for php and insert your data into your database.

ofcourse, you can read the submited data as

`$name=$_POST['name'];`

`$location=$_POST['location'];`

This applies only to PHP; other languages will have other methods to do everything.

---

By the way, did you mean anything special by the "asynchronously .... (on the fly)" in your question?

Answer (score 3):

The data attribute should be an object

```
            $(".div"+increment).change(function(){
               $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "./server",
                 data: {name:"John", location:"Boston"},
                 success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
                      }
            })


           });
```

On the server-side simply retrieve post parameters as usual.
For example, in php you would do something like $_POST("name") and $_POST("location"). 
Response generated by PHP would appear as msg. So you can just echo "Save operation succeeded" in your PHP script after executing your insert.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) instead. It is easier to handle. The drawback is that it doesn't offer error notification.